# Cannot get correct group totals for MongoDB aggregate pipeline for my collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-nodejs-driver

I am trying to use MongoDB aggregation functionality with a very simple query, but for some reason cannot get the final result I'm looking for.

I needed to get a grouping and totals of record statuses in my collection.  A record can have a status (JITM025) of 1-Passed, 2-Warnings, or 3-Errors.  And then I want the total number added up.  The grouping is on the unique group IDs (JITM002). I was somehow able to get the grouping and sorting worked out, but for the life of me cannot get the group totals for each group ID - instead I get the total for all rows in each grouping.

Here is the aggregate pipeline I was able to figure out so far (not sure if its 100% correct):

```js
[
  {
    "$facet": {
      "id":       [{ "$group": { "_id": "$JITM002" }} ], 
      "passed":   [{ "$match": { "JITM025": 1 }}, { "$count": "total" }], 
      "warnings": [{ "$match": { "JITM025": 2 }}, { "$count": "total" }], 
      "errors":   [{ "$match": { "JITM025": 3 }}, { "$count": "total" }], 
      "total":    [{ "$match": { "JITM025": { "$gt": 0 }}}, { "$count": "all" }]
    }
  }, 
  {
    "$unwind": "$id"
  }, 
  {
    "$sort": { "id": 1 }
  }, 
  {
    "$project": {
      "id":       { "$ifNull": [{ "$arrayElemAt": [ "$id:id", 0 ]}, "$id._id" ]}, 
      "passed":   { "$ifNull": [{ "$arrayElemAt": [ "$passed.total", 0 ]}, 0  ]}, 
      "warnings": { "$ifNull": [{ "$arrayElemAt": [ "$warnings.total", 0 ]}, 0 ]}, 
      "errors":   { "$ifNull": [{ "$arrayElemAt": [ "$errors.total", 0 ]}, 0 ]}, 
      "total":    { "$ifNull": [{ "$arrayElemAt": [ "$total.all", 0 ]}, 0 ]}
    }
  }
]
```

Here are the results I'm currently getting in the Aggregate console in MongoDB Compass:

[image]

I get the correct results of 2 groups, sorted by Group ID (750 & 751).  The issue is the totals are not showing up for each group - they are the total for all rows summed up together.  I need the totals to pertain to their own group ID.

Comment: Your query runs fine without any errors. Can you tell how and where you are running the query?

Comment: Here are some examples of [MongoDB NodeJS Driver](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/aggregation/) Aggregation query - in the MongoDB documentation.

Comment: @prasad_, sir I updated my question now that I've made some progress.  Can you help me solve the latest issue I'm having regarding how to correctly sum up the totals based on groupings.  Have spent hours trying to figure this out to no avail.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!